# Ajuda com acentuação no Scanner

Tags: java

Opa, sou novo aqui no site e to começando a programar em Java agora e gostaria de saber se alguém poderia me ajudar a solucionar um problema acerca do Scanner.

O objetivo do meu programa é ate que bem simples. Primeiro ele pergunta o nome e a idade da pessoa e após isso retorna uma resposta lhe apresentando os dados inseridos.

Até ai tudo certo. Porém, quando eu vou colocar meu nome (João) ele retorna JoÃ£o.

Dei uma pesquisada bem profunda mas não encontrei muita coisa a respeito, inclusive encontrei uma resposta aqui no Stack falando pra colocar a "ISO-8859-1" na linha do Scanner, contudo não resolveu.

Irei deixar meu código aqui em baixo e agradeço desde já qualquer ajudar que receber.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DS_Agenda_03 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in,"ISO-8859-1");

        String nome;
        String idade;

        System.out.println("Digite o seu nome:");
        nome = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Digite a sua idade:");
        idade = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Olá " + nome + ", você tem " + idade + " anos de idade, seja bem-vindo(a) ao nosso curso técnico em desenvolvimento de sistemas.");

    }

}
```

Saída:

```
run:

Digite o seu nome:
João

Digite a sua idade:
16

Olá JoÃ£o, você tem 16 anos de idade, seja bem-vindo(a) ao nosso curso técnico em desenvolvimento de sistemas.
```

Comment: Faça um teste: `import java.nio.charset.Charset` e no início do `main`, coloque `System.out.println(Charset.defaultCharset());` para ver qual é o *encoding default* da sua JVM. Provavelmente não é ISO-8859-1, já que esse problema costuma ocorrer quando vc lê os dados em um *encoding* e tenta imprimir em outro. Dito isso, bastaria fazer `new Scanner(System.in)` que ele cria o *scanner* com o mesmo _encoding_ usado para imprimir (`println` usa o *encoding default*). Não tem essa de encoding X é o melhor (ou o "certo"), tem que entender as limitações de cada um e usar de acordo